# How to properly send time_t pointer to function? Encountering valgrind error when trying to do so

Tags: c, time, valgrind, time-t

I am trying to send a time_t to a function by using a time_t pointer variable. I don't get any compiler warnings when compiling my code, but a valgrind error when I run the code with valgrind.

My code:

```
printTime(time_t *time){
    <prints time>
}
int main(void){
    struct tm beginTime = {0};
    time_t *begin = 0;

    strptime("2012",""%Y,&beginTime);
    beginTime.tm_isdst = -1;
    *begin = mktime(&beginTime);    **<-- Valgrind error points here**

    printTime(begin); 


return 0;
}
```

This is the valgrind error I am getting:

```
Invalid write of size 8. (Points at the location pointed at above)
```

Comment: you might want to malloc begin

Comment: @khuderm: Or just do `time_t begin` and pass `&begin`.

Comment: Why are you using a `time_t *`?  Try `time_t begin = mktime( &begintime );` and pass the address of begin?

Comment: Or just pass the `time_t` without using a pointer at all, for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

there are several syntax errors in the posted code.

when compiling, enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings

the following code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. runs without crashing

now the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>



void printTime(time_t *time)
{
    (void)time;
    //<prints time>
}


int main(void)
{
    struct tm beginTime = {0};
    time_t *begin = 0;

    strptime("2012","%Y",&beginTime);
    beginTime.tm_isdst = -1;
    begin = mktime(&beginTime);    // << notice no '*' before 'begin'
                                   // because 'begin' is already declared as a pointer

    printTime(begin);


return 0;
}
```

If valgrind continues to indicate a problem, you could try passing `begin` to `free()`.

I.E. just before the `return 0;` statement insert:

```
free( begin );
```